# A dragon's soul trapped in a ring of mind shielding wants a new body; what magic could enable her to do so?

Tags: dnd-5e, soul

In my D&D 5e campaign, the characters fought and defeated a young dragon of mixed white and silver lineage, and found a [ring of mind shielding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-mind-shielding) on her body. Her original body was destroyed. Unbeknownst to them, her soul has been preserved in the ring and hungers for a way to find a new body.

She is now conversing on a daily basis with the new wearer of the ring and is trying to influence him towards a way that would enable her to achieve corporeal form again. She would prefer a dragon body, but she is also used to assuming humanoid form (from her silver lineage), so that would be acceptable.

**What magic documented in any of the official rule books could enable her to find a new physical form?** Spells, magic items, or magical phenomenon such as a pool of radiance are all acceptable answers.

Comment: Does she want a dragon body, specifically? Or would any physical form be fine?

Comment: Dragon body would be preferable but she is also used to assuming humanoid form (from her silver lineage), so that would be acceptable. I have also been trying to find indications on how dracoliches are created but haven't found anything.

Comment: Has the body been *completely* destroyed (such as with a *disintegrate* spell or by a thorough cremation)?

Answer (score 30):

If the body was destroyed, the dragon's only real options are [Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) and [True Resurrection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/True-Resurrection). All other revival and resurrection spells require a body.

The dragon can theoretically manipulate the player wielding the ring, but that's not really acquiring a new body.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89954/discussion-on-answer-by-miles-bedinger-a-dragons-soul-trapped-in-a-ring-of-mind).

Answer (score 26):

### Maybe (a retroactively cast) Magic Jar and Glyph of Warding?

The [Magic Jar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-jar) spell (PHB, p. 257) enables a creature to send its soul into a prepared "gem, crystal, reliquary, or some
other ornamental container worth at least 500 gp": there's nothing in the text indicating it couldn't be a magical ring. While in that object, their soul can subsequently attempt to possess a humanoid who is within 100 feet of the container.

The spell has quite a few details, and you should study it to make sure you understand all its ins and outs (for example, if the container is destroyed, even while the soul is possessing a new body as a feature of this spell, the caster [i.e. dragon] will die). But the most problematic part of the spell's description for your particular case is the fact that it has a 1 minute casting time.

If this dragon was killed in combat, it wouldn't have had time to concentrate on this spell for a full minute in order to cast it. But it might have been able to set up a [Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) (PHB, p. 245-246) a long time ago to prime the Magic Jar spell with a Spell Glyph. This could have served as a last ditch "escape plan" when it knew it was definitely going to die. Glyph of Warding's spells activate without having to undergo a longer casting time, so the spell could be set off in the midst of combat.

The only problem about this plan is that when you cast Magic Jar, your body becomes catatonic. The dragon would have needed to activate the spell glyph (by doing some pre-arranged trigger for the glyph, possibly something that costs a Reaction, like casting the Shield spell) just a few moments before it died, so that no one in the party would realize this was happening. If you have a party with members who have very high Passive Perception bonuses, it may strain believability that no one noticed the dragon fall down insensitive before the final blow was actually struck. But if this seems believable to you, it's a viable way that the dragon could cheat death (for the moment anyway: again, read the Magic Jar spell carefully to understand its limitations).

### But how did the party Identify the ring?

There's one more important detail you need to think about when considering this strategy: how did the party realize that the ring is a Ring of Mind Shielding? If they took a Short Rest to study the item to learn its properties (DMG, p. 136) you should be fine: they would learn what uses the item has as a magic ring, but nothing else. However, if they cast the Identify spell on the item you could have some trouble because when you cast that spell on an object (PHB, p. 252):

> You learn whether any spells are affecting the item and what they are.

Even Nystul's Magic Aura may not help you hide the fact that the Magic Jar spell is affecting this ring, since that spell only lets you choose the school of magic that appears to be affecting an item, which may not overrule an effect that tells you the specific spell "affecting the item." And while the ring is technically not the target of Magic Jar, it is certainly "affecting it" by causing a dragon's soul to reside within it. The dragon could cast Nondetection on the ring to make the Identify spell unhelpful, but this only lasts 8 hours (and it's a bit unrealistic to think the dragon regularly spent a 3rd level spell slot casting this spell on the ring, just in case).

If you simply told the party that the ring was a Ring of Mind Shielding without going into details about how they discovered this fact, then you should be in the clear. But if the party members specifically mentioned casting the Identify spell on the ring, then you may need to reveal the Magic Jar spell to them, which will likely make the dragon's stay in this dimension quite brief.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; previous comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89952/discussion-on-answer-by-gandalfmeansme-a-dragons-soul-trapped-in-a-ring-of-mind) but they had already [continued this discussion in another chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89944/discussion-between-gandalfmeansme-and-miles-bedinger).